# Powershell Replace fail after test for null

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling data from a database (access specifically using ADO). Then I am preparing the variable for possible insertion into SQL later by replacing any existing single quotes with two single quotes.

Because the value coming from the database is very likely to be null, I test for it and the replace is only supposed to happen if it is NOT null. The value I'm getting it not registering as null when I test it, but when I try the replace, I get the error

> Method invocation failed because [System.DBNull] does not contain a method named 'Replace'.

Here's the section of code 
`$OldAbstract = $rs.Fields.Item("MetaAbstract").value
if($OldAbstract -ne $null) {$OldAbstract = $OldAbstract.Replace("'","''")}`

After pulling the value, I print it and it looks like nothing. I tested it for null, and it says it's not. I tested it for "" and it's not. I even checked to see if it was a space, and it's not. The length is reported as 1... I'm at a loss as to what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're testing for the wrong type of `null` - PowerShell/.net null instead of a database null. Try this (untested):

```
$OldAbstract = $rs.Fields.Item("MetaAbstract").value
if($OldAbstract -isnot [System.DBNull]) {$OldAbstract = $OldAbstract.Replace("'","''")}
```

Comment: Looks like testing for [System.DBNull]::Value worked. Thanks! Final code was:
 if($OldAbstract -ne [System.DBNull]::Value) {$OldAbstract = $OldAbstract.Replace("'","''")}

Comment: Cool. No problem :)